# Single Payment Intent with multiple stripe elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am trying to create a **subscription service** with **stripe** using **react-stripe-js**  but in my front-end at the checkout page, when user submit their card info with some other info (**used useForm** hook to handle form stuff) so at the submit handler I am stuck with the issue of how do I get all the card related information as I used multiple stripe elements to make the form.

I want to collect user card information by calling **createPaymentMethod()** from my front-end but again stuck with the multiple element issue.

Here is the submitPayment function from my checkoutForm.tsx component,

```
const submitPayment: SubmitHandler<AddDetails> = async (data) => {
    if (!stripe || !elements) return;

    try {
      const cardNumber = elements?.getElement("cardNumber");
      const cardExpiry = elements?.getElement("cardExpiry");
      const cardCvc = elements?.getElement("cardCvc");

      const stripePaymentIntent = stripe.createPaymentMethod({
        type: "card",
        card: elements.getElement(CardNumberElement)!, // Only reference of cardNumber element (ISSUE)
      });

    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
```

Any guidance or help appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried running this code? Passing in one element should be all that is needed for this call. When you pass in any of the elements, Stripe can pull the other elements and their data.

Comment: Also is there a reason that you are using `createPaymentMethod` specifically here? That flow is considered to be legacy, when starting out now, it is typically recommended to do a flow more like this one https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements&card-or-payment-element=card-element#create-subscription

Comment: Well I don't know about stripe can pull the rest of the data but for legacy, my API is tested and written for that so I don't want to see unnecessary behavior and I think both the flows can get the job done.